# List all files matching particular names in folders and subfolders using bat file

Tags: batch-file, build-automation

I have attached folder structure . I want to find out all dll starting from Test like Test-A.dll etc [image] Test-*.dll .How could u do it using a bat file .

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the pattern yourself.  Try

`dir /s Test-*.dll`

Saying

`dir /b /s Test-*.dll`

will return the complete path name.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
dir /s X:\Test-A\Test-*.dll
```